# NumberWindow for setting time HH::MM

Tags: pebble-sdk

Pebble GUI has this simple Window with a caption and time edit box the HH:MM format. Used for example to set the alarm time.

Is it available to the developer? The closest thing I found is the NumberWindow but id doesn't seem to do the trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, we do not currently make this window available to our 3rd party developers for them to use in their own apps.

(If you do end up recreating it for your own use, you should make it available to other people as an open source library!)